# throttle messages within an array

Tags: node-red

I have a function that outputs a nested array of messages. ie `return [[message]]`. This is so that all messages are sent on Output 1, which is a requirement since I have no control over the number of messages.

The problem I have is that the mqtt device I'm controlling (Tasmota) can't handle the flood of messages so I need to throttle them within node red. I tried the `delay` node, but that only throttled the array once, rather than throttling each message element within the array.

Comment: Edit the question to show how you configured the delay node, because this is the solution to your problem.

Comment: I didn't configure it - I left it at its default 3s

Comment: The delay node has multiple modes, you need to pick the right one. The default mode is just to delay each input from it's time of arrival not to space them out, you need the rate limit mode to do that

Comment: You're right. I thought I'd tried that, but in hindsight when I did try it my test was flawed. Trying it again gives the result I'm looking for. Feel free to post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As thrashed out in the comments. The delay node has several modes, for this particular problem you need the "Limit rate to" mode.